# AlpineJS pass an array from php to x-init

Tags: javascript, php, alpine.js

I am currently working on a project that involves utilizing PHP and MySQL for data retrieval, and Alpine.js for dynamic front-end interactions. My goal is to pass the array returned from my data fetch in MySQL to the x-init function in Alpine.js, as I am relatively new to using this JavaScript framework. I would like to include what I have accomplished so far:

**data.php**

```
<?php

function dbConn() {
  //   some database connection here using PDO...

}

function getPosts() {
    return db()->query('SELECT u.username,p.* FROM users u JOIN posts p on u.id = p.user_id')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php


$results = getPosts();

print("<pre>".print_r($results,true)."</pre>");

?>

<div x-data="posting()" x-init="fetchPost(<?php json_encode($results); ?>)">

    <template x-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
        <h2 x-text="post.title"></h2>
        <p x-text="post.content"></p>
    </template>

</div>
```

**app.js**

```
document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
    Alpine.data("posting", () => ({
        fetchPost: (data) => {
            this.posts = data;
            console.log(this.posts);
        },
        posts: [],
    }));
});
```

Here is the result on my console and above is my array structure:
[image: screenshot of my array and console]

thank you in advance!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: im getting `undefined` in as a result of my console. how can I pass my array from php function `getFullPostData` to x-init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. You forgot to use `echo`.

```html
<div x-data="posting()" x-init="fetchPost(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($results), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true) ?>)">
```

Comment: i get this error if I use echo: https://i.postimg.cc/jjS65WGN/image.png

Comment: @Unknownymous This is most likely due to the double quotes. I've updated my comment to show how you can escape them

Comment: thank you ! it works! but now my problem is displaying it via `x-for` its kinda weird its not displaying the data.. Did I miss something here: https://i.postimg.cc/FR4tsnc7/image.png

Comment: here is my `app.js` : https://i.postimg.cc/0QQ4QRj5/image.png